# Stansted Airport USB Charging Outlets

Tags: airport-terminals, stn

Is there any USB charging outlet in Stansted Airport?

I forgot my adapter and only have the usb cable of iPhone. Is it possible to charge my phone in the airport? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, though all the ones I recall are after security, and they're pretty heavily subscribed, so you may have to queue, get lucky, or be good at looking desperate.

Comment: Thanks then I should buy an adapter. Is there normal plugs before security section?

Comment: Are you not passing through security?  I wouldn't swear there are loads of charging stations of any kind, regular socket or USB, before security.

Comment: No I will stay overnight so I think I will not made to the airside before 4am

Comment: Just wanted to add my notes. No regular outlets. Only 1 in the toilet and 1 near the security. Please were sitting filthy toilet floor and there was a queue waiting for the outlet. Millions of people and there was even no chair to sit. Worst airport I have ever been to.

Comment: Is this before or after security you're talking about?  Last time I was there, there were a lot of charging opportunities *after* security - just, as I said, very few beforehand.  If that's changed, it would be useful to know.

Comment: Before security section I am talking about. Luckily There were usb charges in national express buses to airport.